# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'protocol') at isURLSameOrigin (isURLSameOrigin.js:57:1) in react.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I was trying to get products from the database with this method, I got all the 4 logs printed in the console 1.calling the try block 2.calling axios ... 4. request resolved
but the products from db was not shown on the screen.

```
const Products = ({ category, filters, sort }) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = async () => {
      console.log("calling the try block");
      try {
        console.log("calling axios");
        const res = await axios.post(
          console.log("request for getting data recieved"),
          category
            ? `http://localhost:5000/api/products/?category=${category}`
            : "http://localhost:5000/api/products/",
          console.log("request resolved")
        );
        setProducts(res.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    };
    getProducts();
  }, [category]);



useEffect(() => {
    category &&
      setFilteredProducts(
        products.filter((item) =>
          Object.entries(filters).every(([key, value]) =>
            item[key].includes(value)
          )
        )
      );
  }, [products, category, filters]);

  return (
    <Container>
      {filteredProducts.map((item) => (
        <Product item={item} key={item.id} />
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Instead of the result all I could see(in the console) after the 4 logs I already mentioned was

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'protocol')
    at isURLSameOrigin (isURLSameOrigin.js:57:1)
    at dispatchXhrRequest (xhr.js:147:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at xhrAdapter (xhr.js:16:1)
    at dispatchRequest (dispatchRequest.js:58:1)
    at Axios.request (Axios.js:109:1)
    at Axios.httpMethod [as post] (Axios.js:144:1)
    at Function.wrap [as post] (bind.js:9:1)
    at getProducts (Products.jsx:23:1)
    at Products.jsx:35:1
    at invokePassiveEffectCreate (react-dom.development.js:23487:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:23574:1)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468:1)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276:1)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:23447:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:23324:1
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:417:1)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:390:1)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:157:1)
```

I actually am using axios for first time and stuck here, please help

I also has the following error printed on my console,

```
index.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: Material-UI: `overlap="rectangle"` was deprecated. Use `overlap="rectangular"` instead.
    at Badge (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:4895:35)
    at WithStyles (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:181340:31)
    at div
    at O (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:345603:6)
    at div
    at O (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:345603:6)
    at div
    at O (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:345603:6)
    at div
    at O (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:345603:6)
    at Navbar
    at div
    at O (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:345603:6)
    at ProductList (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:4146:88)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:336653:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:336586:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:335393:5)
    at App
```

could this be any reason for the issue?

Am getting the below issues

[Screenshot of the errors on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msFtc.png)

Comment: because you are passing `console.log` return value as argument to `axios.post` function.
 also why are you using making `post` request instead of `get`.
it should be `await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/products/', { params: { category: category  } } )`

Comment: @bogdanoff still getting axios errors bro AxiosError
code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
config: {transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
message: "Request failed with status code 404"
name: "AxiosError"
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
response: {data: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n<meta char…>Cannot GET /api/products/</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n', status: 404,
how can I do it without axios?

Comment: Can you post the `/api/products` route definition from your backend?

Comment: const productsRouter = require("./routes/product");
app.use("/api/products", productsRouter);


@lpizzinidev

Comment: You should also post the `productsRouter` code

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a console.log as your first argument and last argument to axios.post call.
Refer `https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example`

Ideally you should also construct your request URL before the axios call.

```
const url = category
  ? `http://localhost:5000/api/products/?category=${category}`
  : "http://localhost:5000/api/products/";
const res = await axios.post(url);
```

Comment: I tried the method you suggested, now I have another error in addition

 POST http://localhost:5000/api/products/?category=women 404 (Not Found)

I had not earlier mentioned the prop type error earlier. can you look at it again

Comment: Have you tried hitting the URL from Postman? This is not an axios issue, it has to do with how you have setup your backend server.

Comment: I dropped the project, the community didn't seem too supportive and I was unable to solve the issue